# Bluetooth - checking rssi in linux

Tags: python, linux, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I want to check rssi parameter and then depends on rssi do some transmission via bluetooth devices from my PC with Python scripts.

I already use:

- `hcitool rssi <MAC>` but this requires connection between devices
  what is not needed for now.
- `btmgmt find` and result is ***Unable to start discovery. status
  0x0c (Not Supported)***
- `btmgmt find |grep rssi |sort -n |uniq -w 33` once with sudo and
  once without sudo.

But when I check `btmgmt find` and  `btmgmt find |grep rssi |sort -n |uniq -w 33` on raspberry pi I got desired result. 
My operating system:

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu

DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04

KERNEL=4.15.0-55-generic

Any ideas why on raspberry do work but on PC does not?

Comment: What version of btmgmt are you using on Linux and what version are you using on the Pi? You can find this out using "btmgmt --help"

Comment: For both I use ```MGMT Version 1, revision 14```. So why on one device it works? And on the other it does not work?

Comment: Use "btmgmt --help" not "btmgmt version". Not sure why, but if the versions are different then this will be the first hint :-)

Comment: So I had a difference between versions like you said. On pc 5.37 which is default version. On Pi 5.43. And I tried to upgrade bluez to one version on pc and PI. It failed :(
So i simply move to other pc and I have one version of btmgmt. 
Thanks for helping me